# Where does the claim that 1lb of weight loss takes 4lb of pressure off your spine come from? Is it true?

Tags: weight, spine, body-weight, posture, pressure

If you Google "4lb spine" there are an awful lot of pages with a [quote along these lines](https://www.summitortho.com/2015/07/27/the-link-between-weight-and-back-pain/):

> For every four pounds you lose, you remove 16 pounds of pressure from your spine.

None of them seem to give a source, as far as I can tell they are all just copy and pasting each other. I was interested in learning more about why this was true, and started to get suspicious as soon as [I found other websites were claiming the same thing for knees](https://www.webmd.com/osteoarthritis/news/20050629/small-weight-loss-takes-pressure-off-knee#:%7E:text=A%20new%20study%20shows%20that,the%20load%20on%20your%20joints.):

> A new study shows that for each pound of body weight lost, there is a 4-pound reduction in knee joint stress among overweight and obese people with osteoarthritis of the knee.

Even if one of these claims is true I am skeptical that they are both true for the exact same number of pounds.

Is there a real study that demonstrates such a relationship for the spine? Was there maybe a study for one body part and people falsely generalized it to other things?

Comment: Do you want to know "where the claim comes from" or "if the claim is true"?

Comment: @BobOrtiz Both? I don't expect any stack exchange users to conduct a study for me but I was hoping maybe somebody would be familiar with where the claim comes from and whether or not quoted articles are sticking to what the study actually asserted or not.